# What is the equivalent to a JavaScript setInterval/setTimeout in Android/Java?

Tags: java, javascript, android, settimeout

Can anyone tell me if an equivalent for setInterval/setTimeout exists for Android? Does anybody have any example about how to do it?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

As always with Android there's lots of ways to do this, but assuming you simply want to run a piece of code a little bit later on the same thread, I use this:

```
new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("tag", "This'll run 300 milliseconds later");
        }
    }, 
300);
```

.. this is pretty much equivalent to

```
setTimeout( 
    function() {
        console.log("This will run 300 milliseconds later");
    },
300);
```

Comment: This is a very good solution for drawer selection and fragmentTransaction

Comment: How can I cancel it if I need to?

Comment: How do you obtain the activity scope within the run() method?

Comment: @Andy like this: `MyActivityName.this.myFunctionOnActivity()`

Comment: @QuentinRoy: `Handler timeout = new Handler(); final Runnable r = new Runnable{...}; timeout.postDelayed(r, 300);` and if you want to cancel it: `timeout.removeCallbacks(r);`

Answer (score 138):

**setInterval()**

function that repeats itself in every n milliseconds

**Javascript**

```
 setInterval(function(){ Console.log("A Kiss every 5 seconds"); }, 5000);
```

Approximate **java** Equivalent

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       Log.i("tag", "A Kiss every 5 seconds");
    }
},0,5000);
```

**setTimeout()**

function that works only after n milliseconds

**Javascript**

```
setTimeout(function(){ Console.log("A Kiss after 5 seconds"); },5000);
```

Approximate **java** Equivalent

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("tag","A Kiss after 5 seconds");
        }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: For the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method, how do you cancel the timer within the activity once that activity has finished?

Comment: @user824294 you can save your Timer instance in a variable and call "cancel()" when you want to stop the scheduled tasks - Timer t = new Timer();  t.scheduleAtFixedRate(...); - And then call t.cancel(); whenever you wish.

Answer (score 18):

If you're not worried about waking your phone up or bringing your app back from the dead, try:

```
// Param is optional, to run task on UI thread.     
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do the task...
        handler.postDelayed(this, milliseconds) // Optional, to repeat the task.
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, milliseconds);

// Stop a repeating task like this.
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: On my phone (Huawei P Smart) the Handler does not wake up the device from sleep mode ([as remarked by apanloco in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819256/659788))

Answer (score 13):

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you should take a look at Android Handlers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

If you previously used javascript setTimeout() etc to schedule a task to run in the future, this is the Android way of doing it (postDelayed / sendMessageDelayed).

Note that neither Handlers or Timers makes an Android phone wake up from sleep mode. In other words, if you want to schedule something to actually happen even though the screen is off / cpu is sleeping, you need to check out the AlarmManager too.

Answer (score 7):

The first answer is definitely the correct answer and is what I based this lambda version off of, which is much shorter in syntax.  Since Runnable has only 1 override method "run()", we can use a lambda:

```
this.m_someBoolFlag = false;
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(() -> this.m_someBoolFlag = true, 300);
```

Answer (score 5):

I do not know much about JavaScript, but I think Timers may be what you are looking for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

From the link:

One-shot are scheduled to run at an absolute time or after a relative delay.  Recurring tasks are scheduled with either a fixed period or a fixed rate.

Comment: Note: It calls you on a background thread, not on the main/UI thread.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a reference to external information that may or may not even contain OPs solution. Please paste in the relevant code OP can use!

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class Clock {
    private Timer mTimer = new Timer();

    private int mSecondsPassed = 0;
    private TimerTask mTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSecondsPassed++;
            System.out.println("Seconds passed: " + mSecondsPassed);
        }
    };

    private void start() {
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTask, 1000, 1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clock c = new Clock();
        c.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was creating a mp3 player for android, I wanted to update the current time every **500ms** so I did it like this

### setInterval

```
private void update() {
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long cur = player.getCurrentPosition();
            long dur = player.getDuration();
            currentTime = millisecondsToTime(cur);
            currentTimeView.setText(currentTime);
            if (cur < dur) {
                updatePlayer();
            }

            // update seekbar
            seekBar.setProgress( (int) Math.round((float)cur / (float)dur * 100f));
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

which calls the  same method recursively

Answer (score 4):

Here's a setTimeout equivalent, mostly useful when trying to update the User Interface
after a delay.

As you may know, updating the user interface can only by done from the UI thread.
AsyncTask does that for you by calling its onPostExecute method from that thread.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Update the User Interface
        }

    }.execute();
```

Comment: **1.** Similarly, `onProgressUpdate()` can also be used to simulate `setInterval()`. **2.** `AsyncTask` runs on a thread pool (or just a single thread), so *a.* it may have to wait until another `AsyncTask` finishes; *b*. it will take up one thread from the pool.

Comment: There are a lot of issues using async task in this context (only one thread and the locking of a thread for no reason) - the other solutions are much better.

Answer (score 1):

As always with Android there's lots of ways to do this, but assuming you simply want to run a piece of code on the same thread, I use this:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       Log.i("tag", "Hai Codemaker");
    }
},0,1000);
```

This code will log Hai Codemaker text every one second.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

You can also use CountDownTimer:

```
class Timer {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun call(ms: Long, f: () -> Unit) {
            object : CountDownTimer(ms,ms){
                override fun onFinish() { f() }
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
            }.start()
        }
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
Timer.call(5000) { /*Whatever you want to execute after 5000 ms*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants -

## Kotlin equivalent to JavaScript setInterval/setTimeout

**IMPORTANT**: Remember to import `android.os.Handler`. Don't get mistaken by `java.util.logging.Handler`

### Timeout equivalent

**Javascript: setTimeout()**

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // something that can be run.
}, 1500);
```

**Kotlin: runOnTimeout()**

```
inline fun runOnTimeout(crossinline block: () -> Unit, timeoutMillis: Long) {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        block()
    }, timeoutMillis)
}
```

**Kotlin: Calling**

```
runOnTimeout({
   // something that can be run.
}, 1500)
```

### Timeinterval equivalent

**Javascript: setInterval()**

```
setInterval(function(){
   // something that can be run.
}, 1500);
```

**Kotlin: runOnInterval()**

```
inline fun runOnInterval(crossinline block: () -> Unit, interval: Long) {
    val runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            block()
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval)
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
}
```

**Kotlin: Calling**

```
runOnInterval({
   // something that can be run.
}, 1500)
```

---

---

---

## Cancellable timeout and interval

If you want to use custom handler so that you can cancel the runnable, then you can use following codes.

### Timeout

```
inline fun runOnTimeout(crossinline block: () -> Unit, timeoutMillis: Long) {
    runOnTimeout(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()), block, timeoutMillis)
}

inline fun runOnTimeout(handler: Handler, crossinline block: () -> Unit, timeoutMillis: Long): Runnable {
    val runnable = Runnable { block() }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, timeoutMillis)
    return runnable
}
```

**Timeout: Calling**

```
runOnTimeout({
    // something that can be run.
}, 1500)

// OR

val runnable = runOnTimeout(mHandler, {
    // something that can be run.
}, 1500)
// to cancel
mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
```

### Interval

```
inline fun runOnInterval(crossinline block: () -> Unit, interval: Long) {
    runOnInterval(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()), block, interval)
}

inline fun runOnInterval(handler: Handler, crossinline block: () -> Unit, interval: Long): Runnable {
    val runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            block()
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval)
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
    return runnable
}
```

**Interval: Calling**

```
runOnInterval({
    // something that can be run.
}, 1500)

// OR

val runnable = runOnInterval(mHandler, {
    // something that can be run.
}, 1500)
// to cancel
mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
```