# how to disable a button for 5 minute after login attempt failed in android

Tags: android

I am Sathya and i am new to android. And i have a doubt that how to disable a button for 5 minutes after log in attempt failed. Even the user close the app and open it again after 2 minutes, then the button should be disable for balance 3 minutes. How to do this. Any please send me some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Hi look at these post (You need to combine these two things) :

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384890/how-to-disable-an-android-button) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771963/what-is-the-equivalent-of-settimeout-javascript-to-android)

In the first post you see how to disable a button in android

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

And in the second post you see how to make a timer

Answer (score 0):

Well I can say that you'll need a Handler, and something to get the actual time for your 2nd question. You get a Handler like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r= new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    if(time < 0){
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //This runs the code again
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000); //This runs the Handler.
```

The 1000 means miliseconds. Which means it will read the code for every 1000 miliseconds = 1 second. You still need to find a way to get the actual time. That's just an example of the handler.

If the user is wrong when putting the password:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```