# Android equivalent of setTimeout and clearTimeout of javascript?

Tags: android, timer

There's an answer for setTimeout https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381353/433570

It doesn't provide info whether we can cancel the timer as we could in javascript.

Is there a timer that is cancellable in android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) of `Handler`

> **public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)**
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

Example code:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i("Tag", "Runnable running!");
    }
};

Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you may use [removeMessages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeMessages%28int%29), [removeCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) methods