# Why countdown timer suddenly executes fast?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently working on a quiz app, What i need for now is to display a

- **Countdown timer**
- **Question**
- **Question Choices**

The countdown timer for Each Question function works fine **IF** the **answer button** is not yet clicked or rather the **MqCheckAnswer** function is not invoke yet.

However, when user clicks an answer, the countdown timer suddenly executes fast.

Instead of a 1 second delay, its delay is like 0.3seconds.
ie. 5,4,3,2,1
output when **MqCheckAnswer** function is invoked: 5,3,2,0

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

**html file**

```
<div *ngIf="MqQuizIsActivate">
<div class="progress">
    {{ current }}
</div>
<ion-row no-padding>

        <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let data of MqlocalQuizData[MqActiveQuestion].QuesChoices">
            <button ion-button color="light" class="B_pclass_choices" (click)="MqCheckAnswer(data)">{{data.Choices}} </button>                                                    
        </ion-col>

</ion-row>
</div>
```

**ts file**

```
//Setup the Quiz
MqSetQuiz() {
  if(this.MqQuizIsActivate){

      if(this.MqActiveQuestion != this.MqlocalQuizData.length){
          // Timer for each Question
          this.current = this.MqlocalQuizData[this.MqActiveQuestion].eaQuesTimer;
          this.MqEachQuizTimer(); 
      }
      else {
      this.MqQuizIsActivate = false;
      this.MqSetQuiz();
      }
  }    
}


//When answer button is clicked
MqCheckAnswer(data){
      if (data.correct) {
          this.MqCorrectAnswer++;
      }
          this.MqActiveQuestion++;
          this.MqSetQuiz();
    }



//Timer for Each Question
MqEachQuizTimer(){
setTimeout(() => {

    if(this.current != 0) {
        this.current--;           
        this.MqEachQuizTimer();
      }
      else {

        this.MqActiveQuestion++;
        this.MqSetQuiz();

      }
}, 1000);
```

}

Comment: its because the setTimeout was not destroyed

Comment: you might be needing this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689125/android-equivalent-of-settimeout-and-cleartimeout-of-javascript/33689555

Comment: Thanks everyone, clearInterval(); resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `current` stores the amount of time remaining.

Rather than calling `MqEachQuizTimer()` recursively you should use `setInterval`.

Also, use a handle (I've called it `this.interval`) to clear the interval when the question is answered like this:

```
MqEachQuizTimer() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.current--;
  }, 1000)
}

MqCheckAnswer(data) {
  if (data.correct) {
      this.MqCorrectAnswer++;
  }
  this.MqActiveQuestion++;
  this.MqSetQuiz();
  clearInterval(this.interval) // this will stop the timer
}
```

This may not be exactly what you want to do but it should set you along the right lines.

Comment: Thank you @danday74, i was able to solve the issue. Thanks