# How to update a value in firebase database after a specific time, like after 10 minutes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There's a Firebase database associated with my project. When the value changes to 2 then after 10 minutes I want the same field to update to 1. The project is on android. 
Is there any way to do it? For creating a specific time interval?

Comment: I don't know what You have tried. You can use java timer to poll the DB periodically.

Comment: You can create one service which run in background and update firebase after 10 minutes.

Comment: Seems like a valid use case for observables.

Comment: Please provide more details. You can use timer class in Android, or deploy a Firebase Function in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ronak Joshi,  but i want to update only when the value changes to 2. Should work like a trigger with timer.

Comment: Is there any way to create a Firebase function which actike a trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a JavaScript function which writes the new value after 10 minutes, and write a Firebase write event trigger to call that function whenever you see a change in value and the value as 2.

If you write this functionality in Android App, it may not update in time if the user disconnects the internet from his phone.

[Documentation for Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Read this documentation. It is fairly easy and an integral part of Firebase as a backend for Applications.

Comment: This is totally accurate but there is a problem. We cannot call our cloud function with a delay, I mean maybe 10 minutes okay but 10 hours is problem because of timeout, pub/sub functions are not the solution neither since it supports only scheduling calls, we need to call our function exactly once after some delaying, am I missing something or there is not a solution for that really?

Comment: The solution to that is, put a listener for new values, and every time a new value is added, a new thread will start as a result of the listener. Either create a scheduled service, and submit the new value to that, or simply put the listener thread to sleep for the given time.

Comment: Thank you Bugs Buggy for your quick reply. So you say there is no solution for cloud functions, we should create our services?

Comment: No no.
You can simply write methods for it, that actually gets executed after the given time. 
I haven't worked with Node in a long time, but there is a util in Java which lets you create "ScheduledThreads".
Do it in your cloud functions only.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with Cloud Functions for Firebase, or alternatively with a timer in Android:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = ...;
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
      new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ref.set(1);
        }
      }, 
    10*60*1000);
  }
  ...
```

Inspired by [What is the equivalent to a JavaScript setInterval/setTimeout in Android/Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817933/what-is-the-equivalent-to-a-javascript-setinterval-settimeout-in-android-java)