# Scheduling change value in FireBase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, real-time-data

In my Firebase Real Time Database I have a variable whose value is "false".
Is it possible to create a schedule in Firebase so that at certains times and days it turns "true" and viceversa?

I know I could do this by App, but I would like to know if it is possible to do this directly from Firebase.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is built into the Realtime Database itself for that, but it is a very common use case for using Cloud Functions. Have a look at the documentation on [running code on a schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) for more information.

Also see:

- [Change the field value in Firebase Firestore automatically after a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958983/change-the-field-value-in-firebase-firestore-automatically-after-a-certain-time)
- [How to update a value every time in the period of 24 hour in Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652196/how-to-update-a-value-every-time-in-the-period-of-24-hour-in-firebase-android)
- [How to update a value in firebase database after a specific time, like after 10 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012797/how-to-update-a-value-in-firebase-database-after-a-specific-time-like-after-10)
- [Delete firebase data older than 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004582/delete-firebase-data-older-than-2-hours)
- [Is there a way to schedule edits to firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638030/is-there-a-way-to-schedule-edits-to-firebase-database) (predates Cloud Functions, but covers many other good options)